# How to disable single post view in wp

Tags: posts, single

I want know, How to disable single post view in wp.
any plugin or setting???

Is there a way to disable single post page, for example when some tries to go to single post page to show not found or 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

You can add to the end of theme's `header.php` file this:

```
if( is_single() ) {
  global $wp_query;
  $wp_query->set_404();
  status_header( 404 );
  get_template_part( '404' );
  exit();
}
```

Note that the `get_template_part( '404' )` function needs `404.php` file in your theme directory.

Comment: Note: For addressing all post types, in particular `page` and `attachment` too, use [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular).